# Add "facet_row labels" in manually produced subplots with Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, label

Consider a figure with subplots, [for example](https://plotly.com/python/subplots/#stacked-subplots) like this:

```py
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1)

fig.append_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[3, 4, 5],
    y=[1000, 1100, 1200],
), row=1, col=1)

fig.append_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[2, 3, 4],
    y=[100, 110, 120],
), row=2, col=1)

fig.append_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[0, 1, 2],
    y=[10, 11, 12]
), row=3, col=1)


fig.update_layout(height=600, width=600, title_text="Stacked Subplots")
fig.show()
```

and we obtain this

[image]

How do I add (manually) labels in the same way as [`plotly.express`](https://plotly.com/python/facet-plots/#bar-chart-row-facets) would place here:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the `fig.layout` in the plotly express example you can see that these texts are [annotations](https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/).

So what you could do is use [`add_annotation`](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Figure.html#plotly.graph_objects.Figure.add_annotation) for each trace.

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1)

fig.append_trace(go.Scatter(x=[3, 4, 5], y=[1000, 1100, 1200]), row=1, col=1)
fig.append_trace(go.Scatter(x=[2, 3, 4], y=[100, 110, 120]), row=2, col=1)
fig.append_trace(go.Scatter(x=[0, 1, 2], y=[10, 11, 12]), row=3, col=1)

fig.add_annotation(
    showarrow=False,
    text="smoker=Yes",
    textangle=90,
    x=1,
    xanchor='left',
    xref="paper",
    y=0.875,
    yanchor='middle',
    yref="paper",
)

fig.add_annotation(
    showarrow=False,
    text="smoker=No",
    textangle=90,
    x=1,
    xanchor='left',
    xref="paper",
    y=0.5,
    yanchor='middle',
    yref="paper",
)

fig.add_annotation(
    showarrow=False,
    text="smoker=Maybe",
    textangle=90,
    x=1,
    xanchor='left',
    xref="paper",
    y=0.125,
    yanchor='middle',
    yref="paper",
)

fig.update_layout(
    height=600,
    width=600,
    title_text="Stacked Subplots",
    legend=dict(yanchor="top", y=1, xanchor="right", x=1.3)
)
fig.show()
```

In the example above the legend is moved somewhat to the right so it doesn't cover the annotations.

To shorten the code you could put the traces in a list and loop through it. For each iteration you could add the trace and the annotation where the x and y position of each annotation are relative to the row (and column).

Comment: But I want this for some plots I am doing with `go.Histogram2d` using two rows with different binning in the y direction, sharing x axis. Is this possible with plotly express?

Comment: Maybe not with plotly express, I can't tell based on the info you've given. Either way using add_annotation like I described in the answer should be able to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear. You're asking about labelling manually produced subplots consisting of `go.Scatter()` traces. And then you're requestion a solution using `go.Histogram2d` *and* Plotly Express but *not* `fig.add_annotations()`. To me, it sounds like you could have asked four very different questions. Still, to me it seems like you'd like to use `px.density_hetmap()` which will produce plots similar to `go.Histogram2d`. And then it all boils down to having the correct data structure and specifying the right `facet_row labels`.

Below is an [example](https://plotly.com/python/2D-Histogram/#density-heatmaps-with-plotly-express) using the dataset ``px.data.tips to produce this plot:

[image]

And if my assumptions are right, this hould be exactly what you're aiming to do.

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()

fig = px.density_heatmap(df, x="total_bill", y="tip", facet_row="sex", facet_col="smoker")
fig.show()
```

#### Edit: Can you have different y-binning for each row?

Yes, I think so. Of course depending a bit on what you mean. But you can freely define the binnings of all axes through:

```
fig.data[n].update(xbins = {'end': 155, 'size': 5, 'start': 0}, ybins = {'end': 11, 'size': 1, 'start': 0})
```

Where n in this case is an element in `[0,3]` and corresponds to the number of subplots. You will also have to specify:

```
fig.update_xaxes(matches=None)
fig.update_yaxes(matches=None)
```

Or you'll get some very funky results.

Compare the following plot and corresponding code snippet with those above to see an example with:

```
fig.data[3].update(xbins = {'end': 75, 'size': 5, 'start': 0}, ybins = {'end': 25, 'size': 1, 'start': 0})
```

#### Plot 2:

[image]

#### Complete code for Plot 2:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()

fig = px.density_heatmap(df, x="total_bill", y="tip", facet_row="sex", facet_col="smoker")
fig.update_xaxes(matches=None)
fig.update_yaxes(matches=None)
fig.data[3].update(xbins = {'end': 75, 'size': 5, 'start': 0}, ybins = {'end': 25, 'size': 1, 'start': 0})
fig.for_each_yaxis(lambda yax: yax.update(showticklabels = True))


fig.show()
```

Comment: Can you make it with different y binning for each row? Completely independent I mean, different range and number of bins.

Comment: Thank you. I would accept the two answers as they are both different approaches to the same problem, and both work. Unfortunately SO does not allow to accept two.

Comment: @user171780 No worries! Feedback and communication is more important to me than getting my suggestion marked as the accepted answer.